# Generating plot from a list of containing rules

Tags: plotting

Using `Solve`, I have produced the following list of solutions to an equation:

```
pts = 
 {{a -> 6, b -> 3}, {a -> 7, b -> 3}, {a -> 9, b -> 4}, 
  {a -> 10, b -> 4}, {a -> 10, b -> 5}, {a -> 11, b -> 3}, 
  {a -> 11, b -> 5}, {a -> 12, b -> 3}, {a -> 12, b -> 4}, 
  {a -> 12, b -> 5}};
```

I would like to know how I can generate a plot of the points $(a, b)$ from the list.

Comment: `ListPlot[{a, 
   b} /. {{a -> 6, b -> 3}, {a -> 7, b -> 3}, {a -> 9, 
    b -> 4}, {a -> 10, b -> 4}, {a -> 10, b -> 5}, {a -> 11, 
    b -> 3}, {a -> 11, b -> 5}, {a -> 12, b -> 3}, {a -> 12, 
    b -> 4}, {a -> 12, b -> 5}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: In addition, `Values[pts]==pts[[All,All,2]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides using [`ReplaceAll (/.)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html), one can also use [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) to extract the data and plot it.

```
ListPlot[Values[pts]]
```